# MAPLE : Problem in solving RLC circuit's ODE with a Dirac as input function

Tags: ode, maple

I am trying to solve the step response of a basic RLC circuit (serial one) with the ODE based on the current i(t) in the circuit. The circuit is driven by `Heaviside(t)` function (the voltage throttle is 1V), so, in ODE, the second member is a Dirac function (`diff(Heaviside(t),t)`.
As a consequence, ODE is the following (L is the inductance, R the resistor and C the capacitance) :

**`L diff(i(t), t, t) + R diff(i(t), t) + i(t)/C = Dirac(t)`** because `diff(Heaviside(t), t) = Dirac(t)`

Initial conditions are the following ones: `init_cond := D(i)(0) = 1, i(0) = 0.`

The components values are `R = 2, L = 1, C = 1/10`.
Maple returns the following solution:

```
i := exp(-t)*sin(3*t)/6 + exp(-t)*sin(3*t)*Heaviside(t)/3
```

The problem concerns the first term:
**`exp(-t)*sin(3*t)/6`** 
which should not be here.
Why does Maple add this term? Maybe I did something wrong?

When I solve this equation with Mathematica I get just this one : `exp(-t)*sin(3*t)*Heaviside(t)/3`.
The simulation with LTSPICE gives the same result than Mathematica. If I use Modelica, it is the same than Mathematice. So I think Maple is a little bit tricky with Dirac. Am I right?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

### PS : The code I used is here :

```
restart; with(plots); with(plottools);with(DEtools, firint, intfactor, mutest, odeadvisor);
param1 := {C = 1/10, L = 1, R = 2};
RLCi := L*diff(i(t), t, t) + R*diff(i(t), t) + i(t)/C = Dirac(t);
init_cond := D(i)(0) = 1, i(0) = 0;<br />
sol_i_an1 := dsolve(subs(param1, {RLCi, init_cond}), i(t));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the initial condition at a point where the solution is not well-defined. The solver has thus to decide how to interpret the condition. Maple appears to interpret it as limit from the left, while the others take it as limit from the right.

In the limit from the right, the initial condition and the influence of the Dirac delta cancel out so that you get zero on the negative half axis. On the other hand, if the limit from the left is non-zero, then the function on the negative half axis can not be the zero function.

So in general, if you force the initial condition with Dirac delta and Heaviside forcings, then you should not have to give explicit initial conditions. But read the documentation on what assumptions get implemented in that case, or how to encode `i(t)=0` for `t<0`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer. I wil try to redefine my initial conditions.
It was not easy to find it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
restart;

_EnvUseHeavisideAsUnitStep; # not defined

       _EnvUseHeavisideAsUnitStep

Heaviside(0);

                undefined

param1 := {C = 1/10, L = 1, R = 2}:
RLCi := L*diff(i(t), t, t)
        + R*diff(i(t), t) + i(t)/C = Dirac(t):
init_cond := D(i)(0) = 1, i(0) = 0:

dsolve(subs(param1, {RLCi, init_cond}), i(t));

    i(t) = 1/6*exp(-t)*sin(3*t)
           +1/3*exp(-t)*sin(3*t)*Heaviside(t)

_EnvUseHeavisideAsUnitStep:=true:
forget(int); # clear remember table

Heaviside(0);

                   1

dsolve(subs(param1, {RLCi, init_cond}), i(t));

      i(t) = 1/3*exp(-t)*sin(3*t)
```

[edit] An alternative for this example,

```
restart;
param1 := {C = 1/10, L = 1, R = 2}:
RLCi := L*diff(i(t), t, t)
        + R*diff(i(t), t) + i(t)/C = Dirac(t):
init_cond := D(i)(0) = 1, i(0) = 0:

Heaviside(0):=1:

dsolve(subs(param1, {RLCi, init_cond}), i(t));

      i(t) = 1/3*exp(-t)*sin(3*t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works! 

The instruction "_EnvUseHeavisideAsUnitStep:=true" was unknown from me.
It was the same for "forget(int)".

I will dig this.
Great thanks.

Comment: OK, good. Regarding "_EnvUseHeavisideAsUnitStep:=true" I found some explanations on the maple help website. It redefines Heaviside function to fit with my purpose.

Comment: And regarding forget(), I found this on Stackoverflow : "All the forget() calls in the code are just there to try and clear previously stored results". So, what is int?

Comment: Yes, the help page for command `Heaviside` has some information. The `int` command performs integration, and gets called by `dsolve` in your example. The call to `forget` is to clear the previously stored `int` result ("memoization"), wihich I made to deal with the fact that I had previously called `dsolve` on the same inputs -- but without setting `EnvUseHeavisideAsUnitStep` to `true`.

Comment: Very good. Thanks a lot for your informed answer :)

Just for information, this problem is happening in other Math Softwares like MATLAB in syms mode, but not with numeric solvers.

Comment: I don't know whether your symbolic engine for Matlab is Maple or (default, nowadays) MuPad. But you could try the same approach there. Another way for Maple is to first assign `Heaviside(0):=1;` which I've added to my Answer.

Comment: In MATLAB software, it is very similar to MAPLE. Instruction to change the heaviside definition is the following one : oldparam = sympref('HeavisideAtOrigin',1);
If you want to restore the default working, just type : sympref('HeavisideAtOrigin',oldparam); or eventually : sympref('HeavisideAtOrigin','default');

Comment: Right, `HeavisideAtOrigin` is the MuPAD way (now sym-engine in Matlab). Let me know if there's anything I could improve in my Answer that would merit it's "acceptance" or upvote.

Comment: Your alternative is perfect. It works fine, and it is very simple. More than the previous solution. 
Although it was not the subject of this topic, but just for information, in MATLAB, I tried HeavisideAtOrigin, but unsuccessfully. And the command heaviside(0) = 1 is rejected. Hopelessly, with numerci solvers like ode45, the results are correct. Thank you for your help. In symbolic way, the results are different between dirac(t) and sign(t), but both wrong.

Comment: Pity the "perfect" solution doesn't merit acceptance of the Answer.